# Freeing pointer content

Tags: pointers, static, stack, dynamically-generated

I doing static and dynamic allocation of 2 differents variables. So, I have the same address for the two pointed-pointer variables.

```
char **input;
char **output = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char));
input = output;
```

My questions are the followings : My former statically allocated variable would free char-sized content up ? Undefined behavior ? Of course, when programm is ending the call stack up to its end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of al, you should allocate as follows:

```
char **output = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*)*(amount of rows));
```

as you are making a list of pointers which are 8 bytes while a char is only 1.
Either way, whenever you call free on output, you free 1 byte, as you allocated the size of 1 char (which is 1 byte).

Statically allocated variables are allocated by the compiler and freed whenever out of scope, so you only need to worry about free-ing dynamically allocated memory (pointers)

input and output point to the same memory space, which has 1 byte reserved on the heap.

You don't free "char-sized content" you free the amount of memory you allocated in your malloc.

Comment: Following your thoughts. When my stacked input on heap is about to be freed, that means it is freeing the 1-byte content on 1-byte reserved memory space. it is right ? So I don't need to call free(output) ?

Comment: @XonoGalaxy False,  the address pointing to the memory you dynamically allocated needs to be freed. Every time you call malloc or calloc whatever address it gives back, you will eventually need to call free on the address (pointer).

Comment: That's the point. My input address is same as ouput one. So when my input is freed, it uses its address to free memory space up ?

Comment: You can see addresses as just a long number that the CPU can use to access the correct memory from the BUS (what BUS is is irrelevant here tho). Whenever you free(address), the address stil remains a long number, there is just no memory associated with it anymore on the heap. Whenever you try to access that address again after it has been freed, you will get an error as the heap doesn't recognize it and it might be used by an other process. So yes, the address in both input and output will remain the same, they just point to "nothing".